# Volume Up key not working but volume down key works

Tags: sound, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Title says it all. Some functionality of the function keys seem to have some random functionality which does not match what it is intended to do. For example, fn F8 is supposed to open up settings which is the default OEM keybinding but it does not seem to work that way. Instead, it's as if it's a replacement for the key 'i'. This problem seems to have risen when I used a global theme with the option "Use default layout from theme". Everything else is normal. Output for audio drivers using `lspci -k`:

```
    00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
            Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
            Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
            Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Any help would be appreciated. If any output is required, let me know. This is strictly a keybind issue and nothing more. **Everything**, and I mean everything works beautifully. No issues.

Hope you have a good day :)

Regards,
Sham.

Comment: Maybe you should visit an `ear specialist` ? 

Comment: Yes, you can tell which version of Ubuntu you have and `xev` output when you press the shortcut. Open Keyboard > Shortcut and confirm it is set to that shortcut. If you can check, possible conflict of other shortcuts.

Comment: @Luuk Just too broke, Can't help it :D

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka There are absolutely no conflicts and everything works fine. It seems my computer has magically decided to bring back functionality. I'll post more in the answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems my computer decided to just work fine with all functionality of the function keys. Turns out, I had done some major changes to my system. I had even rebooted multiple times but nothing worked. As I sat to do my work today, it seems to work fine. Will go back to work now.

Know that anytime your PC is not functioning as well as it needs to, work up from the bottom and just give it a simple reboot :)

Hopefully the problem has been resolved as of now. Unfortunately I have a key issue which causes some problems during my boot. Pressing `Ctrl` during boot seems to work.

Hope you guys have a good day :D

Regards, Sham.